# Custom query with querydsl and jpa

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl

Is it possible to write custom queries with query dsl?

e.g. (self outer join)

```
SELECT test1.SURNAME, test2.SURNAME
FROM Test test1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Test test2 ON test1.SUPERVISOR_WARRANT_NUMBER = test2.WARRANT_NUMBER
WHERE test1.SURNAME LIKE '%Your name%';
```

So I would like to do above with

```
@Repository
public interface Test <TestModel> , QueryDslPredicateExecutor<TestModel> {
    @Override
    @Query("SELECT test FROM Test") /*do outer self join in Query*/
    Page<TestModel> findAll(Predicate prdct, Pageable pgbl);
}
```

The exception I get with above code is:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist
```

If above is not possible, what would be the best approach in java to write dynamic queries (with various joins) with paging?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I am trying the same thing.

Comment: Sorry no. I think you have add joins in your model